# Firebase and flutter - automatic merging of Twitter/Facebook after Google login

Tags: flutter, firebase, facebook, twitter, firebase-authentication

I have the Firebase app set to the default to automatically merge logins from different signin providers and I'd like to keep this (rather than allow different accounts with the same email from different providers)

If I sign in with Facebook or Twitter with a new email, it creates me a Firebase user account. ✅

If I then sign out and sign in with Google using the same email, it merges the account with no problem. ✅

However, if I then sign out and sign back in with Facebook or Twitter, I get an error ❌

> FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/account-exists-with-different-credential] An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.)

I believe this is because Facebook / Twitter emails are not see as "Verified" by Firebase, so it will not merge these into the verified Google one?

There is some documentation [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/account-linking/#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account) on programmatically linking credentials to an existing one, but this seems to assume I already have a credential to link to, which I do not as my `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` not set at the point where I am logging in.

Is the only way to set the Twitter/Facebook emails as verified is via [Auth cloud trigger functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events), or is there another way I can tell Firebase to allow automatic linking of Facebook / Twitter?

EDIT: This is the screen in Firebase that allows one to change the setting for automatic account merging
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as automatic linking. To [link an additional provider to an existing account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking), you will need to be signed in to that account, create a credential for the new provider, and then call `linkWithCredential`.

The normal flow for this is to [call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html) to find what provider(s) the user signed in with before, and then ask them to sign in with one of those again.

---

> If I then sign out and sign in with Google using the same email, it merges the account with no problem.

I expect that you may be testing with a @gmail.com (or other Google-owned) email address, which triggers a special case.

Firebase Authentication recognizes certain email address/provider combinations as preferred, such as @gmail.com and @googlemail.com for Google, @facebook.com for Microsoft, and more. When you sign in to a provider with a preferred email address, that is taken as proof that you own the account - and the existing account is converted to an account of the given provider.

This is only possible with preferred provider email addresses though. You can't trigger it at will.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but can you then explain the Firebase account setting (enabled by default) for "Automatic account merging for the same email via a different provider" ?

Comment: (I've changed the title to be "merging" rather than "linking" as I think maybe this is probably confusing :))

Comment: As far as I know that setting only controls whether you can create multiple accounts with the same email address or not. It doesn't actually merge accounts afaik.